# Building a cube from small bricks such that no lines can be pushed through between the seams

Tags: three-dimensional, tiling

There is a puzzle on fault-free rectangles tiled by dominoes. It is rather known (it is described in Martin Gardner’s “Mathematical puzzles and diversions”,  see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772410/building-a-cube-from-small-bricks-such-that-no-lines-can-be-pushed-through-betwe/3776342#3776342)) and rather old (it is known at least from 1944). A few days ago [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) was riffing on an old contest training question he jousted with 40 years ago, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772410/building-a-cube-from-small-bricks-such-that-no-lines-can-be-pushed-through-betwe) question at Mathematics.SE. It was on a three-dimensional counterpart of fault-free rectangles, asking about the smallest side $N$ of a fault-free cube tiled by $2\times 2\times 1$  bricks. Jyrki Lahtonen proposed an elegant proof that $N\ge 22$ and now he offers a **bounty +500** for a fault-free tiling of a smallest cube or for a proof that there is no such cube. Carl Schildkraut already [improved the bound to $N\ge 24$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772410/building-a-cube-from-small-bricks-such-that-no-lines-can-be-pushed-through-betwe/3776430#3776430).

On the other hand, I expect that a required construction exists for some cubes and it should be shown by a concrete example. But I think that a corresponding tiling is rather irregular, so hard to describe and its construction is a quest rather for a puzzle solver than for a mathematician. So I crosspost it here.

Since the considered tilings are too complicated to be dealt by hand, I wrote and shared an assisting program. It has a simple and intuitive interface, which looks a bit like “[Tetris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris)”, see a [program screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svsOU.png). An the main working field are shown two consecutive layers of the cube of a selected size, parallel to one of three coordinate planes, which can be selected too. The bricks can be added or removed in a few clicks, see the program help for details. To facilitate diversity, each new brick obtains a personal random color. The red dots indicate the unblocked lines, perpendicular to the respective coordinate planes. Constructed partial tilings can be saved and loaded.

Downloads: an [executable file for Windows](https://mega.nz/file/k0hWAIjC#UoBumLMxXc2XPFOBPqw4nJftkrPTOIAv2dzOjwQqokI), a [zip-archive of
Delphi 5 source files](https://mega.nz/file/VtpW3IQT#GthgsN3muduGPLBeJZZ-MzjtaRVARBEHn9-gfbr3jWU).

Good luck!

Comment: I suggest not to share links to windows executables cor security reasons

Comment: @melfnt How then can I share such files?

Comment: I think the source code is enough, I'm no expert.   Executable files can be harmful az we don't have any chance to check what they do

Comment: @melfnt I am not sure this is a choice which is good for all. For instance, my system has a permanent guard in memory, and, as far as I know already for decades, for it is not a problem to run any executable file. Anyway, the linked exe-file should not be download automatically and, when downloaded, it should not run automatically. So it can be checked by antivirus software. On the other hand, for me (and I guess I’m not only one), a compilation of a source code often is a problem, starting from an absence of a compiler. Especially it concerns users with small computer experience.